# How to keep auto incrementing bulk loading

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a bulk loading query:

```
# Load data into categories
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'CategoryData.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE db.Category
LINES STARTING BY '('
LINES TERMINATED BY ')\n'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

My category database has the following schema:

> ID (AutoIncrementing primary key) - Category name varchar(255)

How can i keep the autoincrementing there whilst still bulk loading?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your table structure here?

Comment: I think, using autoincreament ID, has a bad effect on performance of LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one column in the text file (for the name), you can only load the category name:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'CategoryData.txt'
    REPLACE INTO TABLE db.Category(CategoryName)
    LINES STARTING BY '('
    LINES TERMINATED BY ')\n'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    SET ID = NULL;
```

Even if the input file has multiple columns, you can still use the same idea by just ignoring the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the text file, ensure the ID field has `\N` - Effectively `NULL`. This should trigger the auto-increment you're after.